# Python: Creating a List Filter String with Duplicates

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list filter that'll delete a word if it contains a duplicate of a letter. e.g (Deleted {aPPle, AAron, iRRational})
I'm not sure where to proceed, or even start. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
q = 0
x = 0
j = 0
def filter(original, q, x,j ):
for x in range len(orignal):
        for l in original:
    for x in l:
        for j in l:
            if j == x:




input_string = input("Enter names that are separated by space: ")
original = input_string.split()
print("original list:", original)
filter(original, q, x,j)

restricted = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", 
"kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", 
"ww", "xx", "yy", "zz"}
if original == restricted:
#remove???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` to detect adjacent equal letters, then filter out in a list comprehension

```
>>> words = ['apple', 'bob', 'aaron', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> [word for word in words if not any(i == j for i,j in zip(word[:-1], word[1:]))]
['bob', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.groupby` to check any adjacent `char`s are repeated like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> words
['apple', 'bob', 'aaron', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> for word in words:
...   x = itertools.groupby(word)
...   if not any(len(tuple(v)) > 1 for k,v in x):
...     print(word)
... 
bob
bar
```